# Add ability to view tag statistics

Tags: feature-request, tags

It would be great if there was an option to view one tag's statistcs (popularity graphs, for example) against another one's, or even more tags combined.

Things that I'd like to see:

- Popularity graphs

  - usage/time
  - page visits/time
  - answered questions/time
- Most often used with
- Answer questions/unanswered questions for that tag

I'm sure you can come up with more categories.

Comment: Upvoted this, but, honestly speaking, I'd appreciate the most the category that is not here: timeline graphs for the number of questions marked with some tag (per day/week, I mean). I think it would be very thought-provoking, as it gives a pretty nice picture of rise [and fall] for languages/frameworks/paradigms/etc. Also something tells me this one would be the easiest to implement. )

Comment: That's the usage/time graph I proposed, but that's a great expansion you provided there!